# Serving an html file with Flask on Vercel

Tags: flask

This Flask code

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('index.html')
```

on Vercel gives me error output similar to this (once I've removed PII data) when I run it

```
> Built @vercel/python@latest:api/test.py [51s]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/test/.cache/com.vercel.fun/runtimes/python3/../python/bootstrap.py", line 147, in <module>
    lambda_runtime_main()
  File "/home/test/.cache/com.vercel.fun/runtimes/python3/../python/bootstrap.py", line 127, in lambda_runtime_main
    fn = lambda_runtime_get_handler()
  File "/home/test/.cache/com.vercel.fun/runtimes/python3/../python/bootstrap.py", line 113, in lambda_runtime_get_handler
    mod = importlib.import_module(module_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/tmp/zeit-fun-13332f3ebf019/vc__handler__python.py", line 13, in <module>
    __vc_spec.loader.exec_module(__vc_module)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/tmp/zeit-fun-13332f3ebf019/./api/test.py", line 53, in <module>
    from flask import Flask, render_template
  File "/home/test/.mp/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from . import json as json
  File "/home/test/.mp/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/json/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from ..globals import current_app
  File "/home/test/.mp/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/globals.py", line 25, in <module>
    app_ctx: AppContext = LocalProxy(  # type: ignore[assignment]
TypeError: LocalProxy.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'unbound_message'
LambdaError: RequestId: 5db99e3c-81c4-4f8f-bf4d-0b35dc0b13bb Process exited before completing request
    at Lambda.<anonymous> (/home/test/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/vercel/node_modules/@vercel/fun/dist/src/index.js:110:27)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (/home/test/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/vercel/node_modules/@vercel/fun/dist/src/index.js:24:58)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
```

It doesn't seem very complicated. I'm simply trying to serve an html file. Any suggestions as to what the problem is?

And why do I get so much gibberish output? Is it all necessary?

Also, why is it so hideously slow? I update a single word of text in the html and it takes a minute or two to start up again (assuming it doesn't crash). Is it really so tough to serve a simple html file?

FWIW, the HTML is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>

test


</body>
</html>
```

I'm a little worried if it takes this long to process such a simple html file.